# Min and Max are inversed in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I don't know why I have this but when I try to get the min and the max I receive wrong response!

Here is the content for this date :

[image]

And here is my MySQL request :

```
SELECT min(`value`),max(`value`) FROM weather_data WHERE `date`="2015-10-22" AND `type`="temperature"
```

But the response of the MySQL request is this : 
[image: http://puu.sh/kTr1q/af165a2dd9.png]

Do you have an idea of why I have this response?

Comment: second image same as first one

Comment: What is the type of `value`? Let me guess - CHAR?

Comment: shit but I know why I receive this error sorry, this is because I use , and not . for float value

Comment: The value field contain 5,7  14  13,2   why comma instead of float ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `value` is represented as a string.  So, happily, `min()` and `max()` are working correctly.

If the values can be converted on your system, you can use:

```
SELECT min(`value` + 0), max(`value` + 0)
FROM weather_data
WHERE `date` = '2015-10-22' AND `type` = 'temperature';
```

The `+` will do silent conversion.  If the min and max both return 0, then the commas are not recognized, so replace them with periods:

```
SELECT min(replace(`value`, ',', '.') + 0), max(replace(`value`, ',', '.') + 0)
FROM weather_data
WHERE `date` = '2015-10-22' AND `type` = 'temperature';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you have a WHERE clause in your query. What your query actually does is selecting the line where the date is the mentioned date (1 row) and then selecting the max and min value from this row (the actual data)

The right query would look like this:

> SELECT min(`value`),max(`value`) FROM weather_data WHERE `type`="temperature"

Please read the other posts regarding the datatypes too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the data type from string to a numeric type: float or decimal.